# Using IS_Nrf24L01 nuget package for Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core

May I know how to use this nuget package  "IS_nRF24l01p" . I have figured out the command and variable to be declared so that the device can use the NRF24L01p module. But as a beginner in coding, I dont really familiar with the syntax and so on. I just want to do a simple "Hello World". But I am stuck at the initialization step. I follow some tutorial from this website https://technoblogiot.wordpress.com/2016/12/27/raspberry-pi-et-le-controller-driver/
But it is in Vb. But I have to code in C#.
Can anyone teach me on how to do the step like this? Declare the settings for nrf24L01. Thanks in advance.

**The command and variable in Vb**

Namespace IS_nRF24L01p
    Public Class nRF24L01P
        Implements IDisposable

```
    Public NordicChipEnablePin As GpioPin
    Public NordicSPI As SpiDevice

    Public Sub New(SPI As SpiConnectionSettings, Speed As Integer, ChipEnablePin As Integer, InterruptPin As Integer)

    Public Overridable Property timer_SPI As DispatcherTimer
    Public Overridable Property NordicInterruptPin As GpioPin

    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Occurs when data is successfully transmitted.
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   sender:
    '
    '   e:
    Public Event OnTransmitSuccess As OnTransmitSuccessEventHandler
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Occurs when data is received.
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   sender:
    '
    '   e:
    Public Event OnTransmitFailed As OnTransmitFailedEventHandler
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Occurs when data is received with bad payload.
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   sender:
    '
    '   e:
    Public Event OnDataReceiveFailed As OnDataReceiveFailedEventHandler
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Occurs when data is received.
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   sender:
    '
    '   e:
    Public Event OnDataReceived As OnDataReceivedEventHandler

    Public Sub SetChipEnable(value As Boolean)
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Public Sub FlushRXFIFO()
    Public Sub WritePayload(data() As Byte)
    Public Sub WriteRegister(register As Common.Registers, data() As Byte)
    Public Sub SetRegisterBit(ByRef registerByte As Byte, value As Boolean, index As Integer)
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)

    Public Function ReadRXFIFOWidth() As Byte
    Public Function FlushTXFIFO() As Byte()
    Public Function ReadRegister(register As Common.Registers, Optional size As Byte = 1) As Byte()
    Public Function ReadFIFO(width As Byte) As Byte()

    Public Class DataReceiveFailedEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs

        Public DataPipe As Byte
        Public Status As Byte

        Public Sub New(DataPipe As Byte, Status As Byte)
    End Class

    Public Class DataReceivedEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs

        Public DataPipe As Byte
        Public Payload As Byte()

        Public Sub New(DataPipe As Byte, Payload() As Byte)
    End Class

    Public Class DataTransmitFailedEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs

        Public Status As Byte

        Public Sub New(Status As Byte)
    End Class

    Public Delegate Sub OnDataReceivedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    Public Delegate Sub OnDataReceiveFailedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As DataReceiveFailedEventArgs)
    Public Delegate Sub OnTransmitFailedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As DataTransmitFailedEventArgs)
    Public Delegate Sub OnTransmitSuccessEventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Class
```

End Namespace

All I have to do is to declare this in C#

```
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page
    Public WithEvents MTPNordic As nRF24L01P   
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Setup()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Setup()
        Debug.WriteLine("Program Started")      
        Debug.WriteLine("Initialize MTPNordic") 
    MTPNordic = New nRF24L01P(New SpiConnectionSettings(0), 3000000, 12, 13)
    End Sub
```

**The command and variable in C#**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;
using Windows.Devices.Spi;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace IS_nRF24L01p
{
    public class nRF24L01P : IDisposable
    {
        public GpioPin NordicChipEnablePin;
        public SpiDevice NordicSPI;

        public nRF24L01P();

        public virtual DispatcherTimer timer_SPI { get; set; }
        public virtual GpioPin NordicInterruptPin { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Pipe 5 address. Takes only the LSB. Data pipes 1-5 share the most significant
        //     address bytes.
        public byte Pipe_5_Address { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Pipe 4 address. Takes only the LSB. Data pipes 1-5 share the most significant
        //     address bytes.
        public byte Pipe_4_Address { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Pipe 3 address. Takes only the LSB. Data pipes 1-5 share the most significant
        //     address bytes.
        public byte Pipe_3_Address { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Pipe 2 address. Takes only the LSB. Data pipes 1-5 share the most significant
        //     address bytes.
        public byte Pipe_2_Address { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Pipe 1 address. 5 bytes maximum.
        public byte[] Pipe_1_Address { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Pipe 0 address. 5 bytes maximum.
        public byte[] Pipe_0_Address { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     RF Speed
        public Common.RFSpeed Speed { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     RF address width.
        public Common.AddressWidth AddressWidth { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     RF channel frequency. It determines the center of the channel used by the nRF24L01p.
        //     Number from 0 to 125 are allowed.
        public byte ChannelFreq { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     RF db Power
        public Common.dbPower dbPower { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Occurs when data is successfully transmitted.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   sender:
        //
        //   e:
        public event OnTransmitSuccessEventHandler OnTransmitSuccess;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Occurs when data is received.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   sender:
        //
        //   e:
        public event OnTransmitFailedEventHandler OnTransmitFailed;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Occurs when data is received with bad payload.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   sender:
        //
        //   e:
        public event OnDataReceiveFailedEventHandler OnDataReceiveFailed;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Occurs when data is received.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   sender:
        //
        //   e:
        public event OnDataReceivedEventHandler OnDataReceived;

        public void Dispose();
        //
        public void FlushRXFIFO();
        //
        public byte[] FlushTXFIFO();
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   SPI:
        //
        //   Speed:
        //
        //   ChipEnablePin:
        //
        //   InterruptPin:
        //
        //   SPIDesc:
        [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(VB$StateMachine_71_InitNordicSPI))]
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public Task InitNordicSPI(SpiConnectionSettings SPI, int Speed, int ChipEnablePin, int InterruptPin, string SPIDesc = "");
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   width:
        public byte[] ReadFIFO(byte width);
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   register:
        //
        //   size:
        public byte[] ReadRegister(Common.Registers register, byte size = 1);
        //
        public byte ReadRXFIFOWidth();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Used to send data to another nRF24L01p enabled module
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   Message:
        //     Bytes array containing the message to send
        //
        //   TX_ADDR:
        //     Bytes array containing the address of destination device
        public void SendPayload(byte[] Message, ref byte[] TX_ADDR);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Set the nRF24L01p as a Receiver
        public void SetAsPRX();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Set the nRF24L01p as a Transmitter
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   TX_ADDR:
        public void SetAsPTX(ref byte[] TX_ADDR);
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   value:
        public void SetChipEnable(bool value);
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   registerByte:
        //
        //   value:
        //
        //   index:
        public void SetRegisterBit(ref byte registerByte, bool value, int index);
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   data:
        public void WritePayload(byte[] data);
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   register:
        //
        //   data:
        public void WriteRegister(Common.Registers register, byte[] data);
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing);

        public class DataReceiveFailedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public byte DataPipe;
            public byte Status;

            public DataReceiveFailedEventArgs(byte DataPipe, byte Status);
        }
        public class DataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public byte DataPipe;
            public byte[] Payload;

            public DataReceivedEventArgs(byte DataPipe, byte[] Payload);
        }
        public class DataTransmitFailedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public byte Status;

            public DataTransmitFailedEventArgs(byte Status);
        }

        public delegate void OnDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e);
        public delegate void OnDataReceiveFailedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceiveFailedEventArgs e);
        public delegate void OnTransmitFailedEventHandler(object sender, DataTransmitFailedEventArgs e);
        public delegate void OnTransmitSuccessEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I have to do is to declare this in C#

1. [Get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/tutorials/quickstarter/developapp) with UWP application template to create [a simple UWP application](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/develop/Samples/HelloWorld/CS/README.md).
2. Add a Setup() method and instance a nRF24L01P object and configure some settings.

In MainPage.xaml.cs the code will like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Setup();
    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Initialize MTPNordic");
        IS_nRF24L01p.nRF24L01P nRf24 = new nRF24L01P();
        // Use chip select line CS0; SPI speed set to 3 MHz; SPI0 CS0 is 8; Interrupt GPIO selected GPIO 5
        nRf24.InitNordicSPI(new SpiConnectionSettings(0), 3000000, 8, 5); 
    }
}
```

Note: Above is answering your question simple because I don't know how InitNordicSPI implement (if it initialize the SPI and GPIO internally) so maybe you need initialize [SPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/pinmappings/pinmappingsrpi#spi-sample) and [GPIO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/pinmappings/pinmappingsrpi#gpio-sample) for interrupt by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know how can I check whether it initialize the SPI or not?

Comment: @ChenL If my answer solved you question you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If not feel free let me know. As for checking whether it initialize the SPI or not, you need find the InitNordicSPI source code or function description.